# Setting variable to only equal even numbers, and the other to odds

Tags: python, list, variables

I'm having trouble trying to split a list into even and odd numbers with the variables *odd* and *even* representing their respective numbers.

The professor noted that this line of code:

```
odd, even = foo([1,2,3,4,5,6], lambda x : x % 2 == 0)
```

Should split the numbers into odd and even. How do I do something like this? I know how to filter between odd and even numbers, but I'm unsure of how to set two variables in one line equal to their respective parts.

Comment: There's no single function that "unzips" such a list; you just have to iterate over it and build up each of the two returned lists one item at a time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your example `foo` is a function, and returns a pair of variables. For example:

```
def foo():
    a = 1
    b = 2
    return (a, b)

x, y = foo()  # x is now '1', and y is now '2'
```

So you need to create a function that iterates over the input list, and assigns the elements to either an `odd` list or an `even` list. Then return both of these lists, as the above example.

Answer (score 1):

Return a tuple containing the odd values and the even values. The nearest your function could go it is:

```
>>> def foo(l,f):
...     even = filter(f,l)
...     odd = [i for i in l if i not in even]
...     return odd,even
... 
>>> odd, even = foo([1,2,3,4,5,6], lambda x : x % 2 == 0)
>>> odd
[1, 3, 5]
>>> even
[2, 4, 6]
```

This assignment is known as *Tuple Unpacking*. In this way when you return comma separated variables and the same number of variables on the left hand side, each of the variables on the left hand side will be respectively assigned to those on the right hand side.

Comment: An interesting downvote... Hmmm, what could have gone wrong here?